# PHP upload image script form doesn't work when my client is an iOS

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I have created a file upload `form` `script` but it doesn't work when I tried using it with an `iPhone`.

I get no error, or `error code 0` when I `var_dump` the code. If I use another platform such as `Android`, `Windows Phone` or `Desktop`, it uploads the file successfully.

My code:

```
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*20000; //20 mb
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/beta/images/'; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to execute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded filesize
            $info = getimagesize($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f]);
            if ($info === FALSE) {
                die("Unable to determine image type of uploaded file");
            }
            if (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
                die("Not a gif/jpeg/png");
            }

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.time().'_'.$name))
                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`move_uploaded_file` function `return false` as the `$count` variable remain `0`.

It only won't upload when I access the file upload script with an `iPhone`.

Form code:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"/><Note: Supported image format: .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .gif (Size up to 2mb)<input type="submit" value="Upload!" id="selectedButton"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you use the exact same code on your iOS app as your Android app? If not , why don't you add the code to the iOS that you use to upload?

Comment: I'm not using app. It's a html form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before on an iPhone. The image name was xxx.JPG and my code was checking the file extension but it was case sensitive.

Have a go adding JPG to your list of valid extensions.

Failing this, write the value of $_FILES to a file and then see exactly what you're receiving on submission.

Comment: I can't believe upper case was the problem. Crap, I spend like hours trying to figure it out and this seemed to be the problem.